# browser.debugger() doesn't pause browser

Tags: angularjs, debugging, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using WebStorm 9 and Protractor version 1.8. I prefer to use Chrome (version 41.0.2) for my debugging and am able to able to debug the normal application in Browser and also in WebStorm.

However debugging Protractor is failing.

```
Protractor --version //1.8.0
Angular // 1.3
OS // Windows 7
```

Here is a simple test

```
it('check title', function () {

    browser.get('/e2e/employeeForm.html');
    browser.sleep(5000);
    browser.debugger();

    var title = element(by.className('someClass'));
    expect(title.getText()).toMatch('Employee Form');

});
```

In terminal, in one console I started webdriver `webdriver-manager start`. In other, I ran the command

`protractor debug prc.conf.js`

Following is the output:

```
Starting debugger agent.
debugger listening on port 5858
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
connecting... ok
break in timers.js:79
77 }
78
79 function listOnTimeout() {
80 var msecs = this.msecs;
81 var list = this;
debug>
```

I hit `c` and Enter. It continues and all tests fails. Even browser doesn't render my page. `browser.debugger()` is ignored.

Can anyone suggest me anything here?

Comment: What version of node are you using?  (This might be related: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1893)

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug with protractor 1.8.0 and windows detailed here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1822

The bug has been fixed in master (https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1850), and will be released in the next version of protractor.